# Variables viewer on Eclipse debugging evaluates Python property automatically

Tags: python, eclipse, configuration, pydev

When I new some instance, its __ init __ will do, e.g.

```
self._regex = value  
self._regex_dict = {}
```

In the Eclipse/PyDev debugger's variables view,`self._regex_dict` is not equal to empty but has one entry instead.

It seems variables view generates`self.regex`automatically, and unfortunatelly, the following method is defined and will output one entry to`self._regex_dict`

```
@property
def regex(self):
    ...
    self._regex_dict[language_code] = compiled_regex
    return self._regex_dict[language_code]
```

Is there any configuration to prevent such auto-generation behavior of Eclipse/PyDev debugger's variables view?

P.S. If I turn off the Eclipse/PyDev debugger's variables view, this issue won't happen. But I really need it when debugging

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well, when the debugger hits a breakpoint and you have the variables view visible, it'll do a dir() on all the objects in the context and for each value it'll do a str() to show them.

As you have a property (regex) which will add an entry to your dict 'behind the scenes' when accessed and as the variables view will definitely try to show that value to you, I'm not sure you have a way around it other than changing your program or changing the debugger itself (it'll get the vars at pydevd_vars.frameVarsToXML).